# how to add date to the existing cell value of date using vba

Tags: vba, excel

I have to add one month extra to the cell value date.

I have date in the cell i.e 201604. I need to add extra month to that date and have to use that data as a file name. example: sree 201605.xlsm

My code:

```
Sub vba()

Check_date = Worksheets("abc").Range("A2").Value 
format_date = format(dateadd(check_date("m", 1), "yyyymm"))

end sub
```

can someone please answer me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim n As Long, s As String, d As Date

    n = Range("A1").Value
    d = DateSerial(Left(n, 4), Right(n, 2) + 1, 1)
    s = Format(d, "yyyymm") & ".xlsm"
    MsgBox s
End Sub
```

[image]